# Error "matplotlib is not a package" on Mac problems

Tags: macos, python-3.x, matplotlib

Getting the `No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; matplotlib is not a package` error when trying to  run:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot

plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[4,7,8,12])

plt.show()
```

Im running python 3.3, and have installed the correct matplotlib, and six library. i have checked this by running pip list.

I have also tried running the file in terminal, and when i do this the error changes from `matplotlib is not a module` to `no module named pyplot`.

Comment: when you are importing `matplotlib.pyplot` and then calling `plt`, it doesn't make sense!! you should `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and then call `plt.plot`

Comment: Sorry not sure why the code hasn't copied correctly. The first line does infact say: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt.